# How would I generate combinations of items within Polars using the native expression API?

Tags: list, python-itertools, python-polars

Is there a way to generate combinations of items within a list inside a Polars column without resorting to `.map_elements()` + **itertools** for each row?

This is my current solution:

```py
import polars as pl
import itertools

(pl.DataFrame({'col': [['a', 'b', 'c']]})
   .with_columns(pl.col('col')
                   .map_elements(lambda list_o_things: [sorted((thing_1, thing_2))
                                                        for thing_1, thing_2 
                                                        in itertools.combinations(list_o_things, 2)])
                )
)
```

which returns this:

`[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'c']]`

Comment: Side note: you can modify the "display" settings e.g. [`pl.Config(fmt_table_cell_list_len=-1, fmt_str_lengths=120)`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/config.html) to help see the full result.

Comment: Do you really want everything in a list-typed column instead of a long column with elements?

Comment: A native Rust version of `.list.combinations()` could also be a decent suggestion for a feature request.

Comment: jqurious - thanks, the Config params are super useful. And just added that feature request!
BallpointBen - I'll likely explode it after, or maybe do something else, but just wanted to keep the example simple, but all suggestions are welcome! Assume I don't know best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explode the nested structure, do a cross join with itself, filter out the redundant entries, concat to list, and implode to nested list.

```
df=pl.DataFrame({'col': [['a', 'b', 'c']]})
(
    df
    .explode('col')
    .join(
        df.explode('col'), how='cross')
    .filter(pl.col('col')<pl.col('col_right'))
    .select(pl.concat_list('col','col_right').implode())
    )
shape: (1, 1)
┌──────────────────────────────────────┐
│ col                                  │
│ ---                                  │
│ list[list[str]]                      │
╞══════════════════════════════════════╡
│ [["a", "b"], ["a", "c"], ["b", "c"]] │
└──────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Comment: This blows up my memory when `.collect(streaming=True).write_parquet('file.parquet')` (looks like the `.list().concat()` breaks streaming) is there a better way to do this for larger than memory datasets?

Comment: The thing that breaks streaming and prevents `sink_parquet` from working is the `.select()` line. If you comment that out then you can stream the results to a file. Maybe you can save an intermediate file and then in a separate step(s) read that file and mash the columns together.